# Composer, autoload, psr-4

Tags: php, composer

С composer работаю в первый раз.
Запустил "composer init", создал проект, установил все необходимые зависимости. Теперь я хочу в папку vendor положить свой "пакет". Создал там папку, а в ней еще одну, получилось что то вроде 'vendor/author/package'.
В конечную папку положил файл composer.json со следующим содержимым:

```
{
    "name": "author/package",
    "description": "Description my package",
    "license": "FREE",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Author Name",
            "email": "author@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Author\\Package\\": ""
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

И когда я вызываю в коде свой класс

```
$myClass = new \Author\Package\Myclass;
```

Автолоадер его не находит. Я понимаю что дело в регистре первых букв. Подскажите как "научить" composer видеть мой пакет именно в таком формате как есть, то есть название папок в нижнем регистре, а namespace каждое слово с большой. Спасибо.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не стоит в `vendors` просто так что-то ложить. Вместо этого, добавьте свой модуль в зависимости.

Пример `composer.json` родительского проекта:

```
{
    ...
    "require": {
        ...
        "component-name": "dev-master" // см. пункт 1, 2
    },
    ...
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/author/package.git" // см. пункт 3
        }
    ]
}
```

1. Значение `component-name` должно совпадать с `name` из `composer.json` компонента
2. `dev-master`, чтобы стянуть с `master` ветки, либо `vX.Y.Z`, если в репозитории проставлены теги *([теги](https://getcomposer.org/doc/02-libraries.md#tags), [ветки](https://getcomposer.org/doc/02-libraries.md#branches))*
3. `author/package` может не совпадать ни с чем вышеперечисленным *([документация](https://getcomposer.org/doc/02-libraries.md#publishing-to-a-vcs))*

Если репозиторий приватный - начать можно отсюда [HTTP basic authentication](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/http-basic-authentication.md#http-basic-authentication)